# Linux Asynch IO - difference between aio.h and libaio.h

Tags: linux, sockets, asynchronous, linux-kernel

I have started looking at a new paradigm I didn't know called asynch IO in Linux.

My goal is to use async IO targeting sockets to write high-performance efficient servers. The reason is that my application is IO-bound.

While searching for more information I came across the following 2 introductions.

1. [Posix AIO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/)
2. [Linux AIO interface](http://code.google.com/p/kernel/wiki/AIOUserGuide)

In a asynchronous framework, the situation I would like to avoid is to create a new thread for each notification I need to process asynchronously since it will kill my application.

My questions are the following:

1. Do the behind-the-scenes of these 2 frameworks address this problem?
2. If yes what would you suggest having in mind socket?

Regards

AFG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of these are really intended for sockets.

The POSIX AIO interface creates threads that use normal blocking IO. They work with the buffer cache and *should* in principle even work with sockets (though I've admittedly not tried).

The Linux kernel AIO interface does not create threads to handle requests. It works *exclusively* in "no buffering" mode. Beware of non-obvious behaviour such as blocking when submitting requests in some situations, which you can neither foresee nor prevent (nor know about other than your program acting "weird").

What you want is nonblocking sockets (a nonblocking socket is "kind of asynchronous") and `epoll` to reduce the overhead of readiness notification to a minimum, and -- if you can figure out the almost non-existing documentation -- `splice` and `vmsplice` to reduce the IO overhead. Using `splice`/`vmsplice` you can directly DMA from disk to a kernel buffer and push to the network stack from there. Or, you can directly move pages from your application's address space to kernel, and push to the network.
The downside is that the documentation is sparse (to say the least) and especially with TCP, some questions remain unaddressed, e.g. when it is safe to reclaim memory.

Comment: POSIX AIO isn't necessarily implemented with threads - the threaded implementation is part of portable AIO implemented in GLIBC, especially since at one point (pre-2.5?) Linux lacked AIO support in kernel.

Comment: Well, "POSIX" as such doesn't mandate it, that's true. However, under Linux/Glibc (which the question is about) it certainly is. And funny as it sounds, the Glibc threaded implementation is much better than the kernel flavour.

Comment: From what I heard, the kernel implementation ended up being scaled down from initial scope, where it supported, among other things, network communications.

Though if one wants that flavour of I/O, unfortunately *nix world is lacking compared to VMS and NT (which derives its AIO from VMS' one).

Comment: Though I could live with the "no sockets" thing. What I dislike most about the kernel implementation is that it is not possible use the buffer cache, although patches to enable this ability have been around for 5 or so years (and been turned down for "no need") and that it isn't truly asynchronous. When you submit an async request, the last thing you expect to happen is to have the call suddenly block indefinitely. However that's just what happens when there are enough outstanding requests or enough large requests. The Glibc POSIX implementation never blocks, which is how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

For purpose of network programming, you will want **event** based I/O, implemented (in most basic form) with **select(2)** call, and on some systems with **poll()**, **epoll()**, **kpoll()** etc.

POSIX AIO (of which Linux AIO is an implementation), doesn't necessarily work on sockets (It did at some point in Linux 2.5 codebase, but I can't be certain it's still possible).

High-performant **socket I/O** on Unix is instead done in event-based manner, where you process incoming events in a loop. An event can be "socket is ready for write", "socket has new data" etc., then react on them.