# How to accelerate writing to tcp socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a web server, that returns tiny JSON (about 200 bytes). The business logic spends about 2-3 microseconds, but writing to socket spends about 25 microseconds. I use `write` for single buffer and `writev` for multiple buffers.

I already disabled Nagle's algorithm by enabling TCP_NODELAY. Are there any other ways to accelerate writing?

Listening socket options:

```
......
if (listen(sfd, SOMAXCONN) == -1) { ... }

int val = true;
if (setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &val, sizeof(val)) == -1) { ... }
if (setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT, &val, sizeof(val)) == -1) { ... }
if (setsockopt(sfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, &val, sizeof(val)) == -1) { ... }

auto flags = fcntl(sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
if (flags == -1) { ... }
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(sfd, F_SETFL, flags) == -1) { ... }
......
```

Accepted sockets options:

```
......
int infd = accept(sfd, &in_addr, &in_len);
if (infd == -1) { ... }

auto flags = fcntl(infd, F_GETFL, 0);
if (flags == -1) { ... }
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(infd, F_SETFL, flags) == -1) { ... }

int val = true;
if (setsockopt(infd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &val, sizeof(val)) == -1) { ... }
......
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this really a problem? Is this *the* major bottleneck in your application? Is it not "good enough"?

Comment: Use async writes, `man aio(7)`

Comment: Perhaps then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386043/linux-asynch-io-difference-between-aio-h-and-libaio-h

Comment: Nagle doesn't accelerate "writing". It accelerates sending of partial packets. But how is that going to be relevant here? Either you have many, many of these 200 byte packets (and then Nagle doesn't matter), or you have only a few (Nagle now matters, but the 25 microseconds no longer does). I don't think `aio` is the solution. It's generally not that relevant for buffered output anyway, but it also only moves the 25 us to another thread.

Comment: As far as I know disabling of Nagle's algorithm forces sending packet immediately without waiting next portion of data.

Comment: Indeed, which is why Nagle is generally a slowdown, not a speedup.

Comment: Your setup is unclear to me. What returns tiny packets to where? From where? Why is 25ms a problem? Does one client need to get 2,000 packets? Or 2,000 clients need to get one packet each?

Comment: What are you timing? Round trip time? One-way end to end time? Time spent in `write()`?

Comment: @MSalters: Nagle improves throughput but may hurt latency. It seems the OP is interested in reducing latency, but this could certainly be made more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The Nagle Algorithm might help, but it only helps when your bottleneck is the round-trip transfer itself. Assuming your "write time" is only based on packet TX time (eg: time from writing to a socket to the data leaving adapter), disabling this algorithm is not going to fix your solution.  Based on the inherent stream nature of a TCP connection, there may not be a solid workaround...If the timing is really that critical, consider using UDP, especially since your packets are small. If TCP is a necessity, maybe look into using a different socket library. Honestly speaking though, your timing does not seem all that horrendous to me.